# VSTS - Take app offline before deployment

Tags: c#, azure, tfs, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I'm getting this problem using VSTS continuous deployment to azure

```
Web Deploy cannot modify the file 'XXX' on the destination because it is locked by an external process
```

the solution provided in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813629/azurew-website-continious-deployment-web-deploy-cannot-modify-the-file-xxx-o) is to manually restart my app in azure, however he's not using VSTS and the question was asked 2 years ago, is this issue fixed on the current VSTS and if so, I would like to know how because I'm having the same problem as the link referenced above.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "EnableMSDeployAppOffline" feature to set your app offline before deployment by following the instruction here: [Web publishing updates for app offline and usechecksum](http://web.archive.org/web/20190111193106/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/29/web-publishing-updates-for-app-offline-and-usechecksum/).

If it does not work, you can also create a PowerShell script as following to stop the app, deploy and then restart the app:

```
    param($websiteName, $packOutput)

    $website = Get-AzureWebsite -Name $websiteName

    # get the scm url to use with MSDeploy.  By default this will be the second in the array
    $msdeployurl = $website.EnabledHostNames[1]


    $publishProperties = @{'WebPublishMethod'='MSDeploy';
                            'MSDeployServiceUrl'=$msdeployurl;
                            'DeployIisAppPath'=$website.Name;
                            'Username'=$website.PublishingUsername;
                            'Password'=$website.PublishingPassword}

    Write-Output "Stopping web app..."
Stop-AzureWebsite -Name $websiteName

Write-Output "Publishing web app..."
$publishScript = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Publish\Scripts\default-publish.ps1"

. $publishScript -publishProperties $publishProperties  -packOutput $packOutput

Write-Output "Starting web app..."
Start-AzureWebsite -Name $websiteName
```

PowerShell Script from: [Build and Deploy your ASP.NET 5 Application to an Azure Web App](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/deploy-aspnet5).

Comment: the first one didn't work but for the 2nd one I added 2 more steps to my build definition, one to stop , then deploy, then start it again and it's working smoothly

Answer (score 4):

Essentially you need to stop - deploy - restart .

You have many options to do it but to more easy would be:

1- Extention: **Azure App Services - Start and Stop** 
you can try the extension "Azure App Services - Start and Stop" https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rbengtsson.appservices-start-stop

2- **AzureCLI task**
From the build or Deployment windows Add am Azure CLI task (currently in Preview)

Add one before the Deployment task 
with Inline script:

```
azure webapp stop --resource-group NAME_OF_YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP --name WEBAPP_NAME
```

Add another one after the Deployment task 
with Inline script:

```
azure webapp start --resource-group NAME_OF_YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP --name WEBAPP_NAME
```

I hope that help.

[image]