# Azure DevOps Pipeline to non-Azure site via FTP App_Offline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

1. I'm deploying from an Azure DevOps pipeline to a *non-Azure website* I have only ftp access to.
2. The ASP.NET Core 5.0 site is running, so I need to drop an App_Offline.html in there, do my FTP deploy, then get rid of the App_Offline again.

Without the App_Offline you can't overwrite the .dll bits of the active site, and I can't get it to delete them either, so I definitely need to take the site offline. I do not want to do that manually as it makes the pipeline less useful.

I can't be the only/ first person to need to do this - does anyone have some YAML which will do that specific job please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the upload to work...

Step 1: Add an App_Offline.htm file to the repo

Step 2: add an initial FTP step to take the site offline *before* the ftp upload of the site itself. Like this (settings are similar to those used for the actual deployment ftp, except for the filePatterns):

```
- task: FtpUpload@2
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: 'inputs'
    serverUrl: 'ftp://ftpx.ftptothesite.com' # 3rd party hoster site address
    username: '$(ftpUsername)'
    password: '$(ftpPassword)'
    rootDirectory:  '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/s'
    filePatterns: 'app_offline.htm'
    remoteDirectory: '/web/content/'
    preservePaths: true
    trustSSL: true
  displayName: 'Take site offline'
```

That makes the upload work, but leaves the remote site offline (because there's an app_offline.htm in the root there).

Step3: Delete app_offline.htm
Note that the FTP task has a "customCmds" parameter which MS describe as:

> Optional FTP Commands that will be sent to the remote FTP
> server *upon connection*

My italics. The custom commands are run before the FTP task they are defined in, not after. Hence I needed one more FTP upload task, of something benign, but with a `DELE /web/content/app_offline.htm` as the last command. Note that the full path is needed, presumably as this runs before the remoteDirectory is set up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "EnableMSDeployAppOffline" feature to set your app offline before deployment by following the instruction here: [Web publishing updates for app offline and usechecksum](http://web.archive.org/web/20190111193106/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/29/web-publishing-updates-for-app-offline-and-usechecksum/).

If it does not work, you can also add a [PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) to run script as following to stop the app, deploy and then restart the app:

```
    param($websiteName, $packOutput)

    $website = Get-AzureWebsite -Name $websiteName

    # get the scm url to use with MSDeploy.  By default this will be the second in the array
    $msdeployurl = $website.EnabledHostNames[1]


    $publishProperties = @{'WebPublishMethod'='MSDeploy';
                            'MSDeployServiceUrl'=$msdeployurl;
                            'DeployIisAppPath'=$website.Name;
                            'Username'=$website.PublishingUsername;
                            'Password'=$website.PublishingPassword}

    Write-Output "Stopping web app..."
Stop-AzureWebsite -Name $websiteName

Write-Output "Publishing web app..."
$publishScript = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Publish\Scripts\default-publish.ps1"

. $publishScript -publishProperties $publishProperties  -packOutput $packOutput

Write-Output "Starting web app..."
Start-AzureWebsite -Name $websiteName
```

See thread: [VSTS - Take app offline before deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234007/vsts-take-app-offline-before-deployment) for more details.

Comment: The key thing is that I only have ftp access to the site, and it's non-Azure, hosted with a third party hoster.