# File locked when deploying to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-webapps

I have an MVC application and I have been deploying it to Azure. But, the last time i did, an error occurred:

```
  Web Deploy cannot modify the file 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll' on the
  destination because it is locked by an external process. In order to allow 
  the publish operation to succeed, you may need to either restart your 
   application to release the lock
```

I restarted the app, and the file is still locked. I looked at this ( http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FILE_IN_USE) but the language is too cryptic. Has anyone else encountered this problem or can decipher what Microsoft said about syncing in the article? Thanks

**Edit**
I found this ([VSTS - Take app offline before deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234007/vsts-take-app-offline-before-deployment/37245766#37245766)) but do not know what values to give variables like $packOutput,$msdeployurl $website etc

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813629/azurew-website-continious-deployment-web-deploy-cannot-modify-the-file-xxx-o Could you try the answer provided ?

Comment: That post said to restart the app. I did that. I'll keep looking. Thanks

Comment: Is that assembly actually required for your MVC site? If not, try excluding it from your deployment.